# Reading XML and JS from one file

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml

I have a file like this:

```
<note type="mail" status="created">
  <to>Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>

{
  name: 'Mail',
  messageType: 'Reminder',
  getFullTitle() {
    return 'Reminder ' + Date.now();
  }
}
```

I need to parse this file using Node.js and get separate XML and JS object like this:

```
{
  xml: <xml here>,
  js: {
    name: 'Mail',
    messageType: 'Reminder',
    getFullTitle() {
      return 'Reminder ' + Date.now();
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Assuming the the file isn´t getting isanely big and the empty newline is always there I would read the entier thing into a string with fs api node provides, then split for blank lines (double line break should work, but otherwise plenty of examples on stackoverflow on how to do this part). Then you can JSON.parse the [1] and set [1].xml to [0].

Answer (score 2):

Not easy, because the XML parser will throw an error when it hits the "{" after the end tag, and there's no good way to tell it where to stop parsing.

Try to persuade whoever is providing the data in this form that they are placing an undue burden on recipients of the data. Standards are good: XML is good, JSON is good, mixing them up like this is bad.

Comment: just gonna throw an idea here, use a stream parser and on error, mark the position and split. i'm not sure if it's feasible. just an idea.

Comment: The XML parser probably won't read the stream one byte at a time; the position of the stream at the time the XML parser throws a wobbly will be some arbitrary distance ahead of the actual end of the XML.